# some trouble whit my Jquery-Sub-navigation code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover

I have some trouble whit my Jquery-Code and I don’t understand why…

I am trying to build a navigation whit a vertical drop-down:

The main navigation already has a script whit a roll-over image that works, also the same goes for the Ajax-call for the content…

Anyway I tried it whit a self-written Code: 
This is my Jquery-Code:

```
function nav() {
    $('ul li').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find('#submenu').show();
    });
    $('ul li').mouseleave(function() {
        $('ul li #submenu').hide();
    });
    $('ul li #submenu').mouseleave(function() {
        $('ul li #submenu').hide();
        ;
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    nav();
});
```

The HTML:

```
<li><a href="#home"><img class="fadeim" src="themes/menu/home=1.png" data-hoverimg="themes/menu/home=2.png"/></a></li>

    <li><a href="#lager"><img class="fadeim" src="themes/menu/lager=1.png" data-hoverimg="themes/menu/lager=2.png" /></a></li>

   <ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#">Mashable</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CNET</a></li>
</ul>

    <li><a href="#anlaesseN"><img class="fadeim" src="themes/menu/anlaesse=1.png" data-hoverimg="themes/menu/anlaesse=2.png" /></a></li>

      <ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#">Mashable</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CNET</a></li>
</ul>

    <li><a href="#images"><img class="fadeim" src="themes/menu/foto=1.png" data-hoverimg="themes/menu/foto=2.png" /></a></li>
```

Could someone please help me solving this?
Thank you

Comment: what is the trouble here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `.` instead of `#` in `$(this).find('#submenu').show();`.
You have no ID `#submenu`, only classes `.submenu`.

Corrected code should be:

```
function nav() {
    $('ul li').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find('.submenu').show();
    });
    $('ul li').mouseleave(function() {
        $('ul li .submenu').hide();
    });
    $('ul li .submenu').mouseleave(function() {
        $('ul li .submenu').hide();
        ;
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    nav();
});
```

**EDIT**: check your markup also, you are looking for `.submenu` with `.find()` but `ul.submenu` is not children to li is actually on the same DOM level (.siblings() would work here), so to get more correct markup you should have nested ul inside li, and not nested ul inside ul. Then you can use the code I wrote above. Like this:

```
<li><a href="#lager">lager</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="http://www.mashable.com">Mashable</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.cnet.com">CNET</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rTDzk/) (you need to fix the css...)

Comment: @adho12, sometimes its nice to have other people looking at the code and help with things we don't see. Hope it helped!, did you get it working?

Comment: sorry but could you help me again?

i have a this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adho12/RA4hQ/ here but I am not getting it runing...
sorry to ask and thanks